# In Autodesk Maya using python I built a textScrollList, how can I return what is deselected?

Tags: python, maya

In Maya I created a texScrollList when I deselect I run these two prints.

print cmds.textScrollList("menuName", si=True, q=True)
print cmds.textScrollList("menuName", di=True, q=True)

Both of these return 'None' when I deselect from my textScrollList. Is there anyway to return the name of what I deselected?

Comment: No response! :(

Comment: Try the query kwarg first... I honestly don't know if it will make a difference in python, but I think it does in mel, and when I switched to python I was just in the habit of putting it first... I kind of doubt it will since kwargs is a dicta, but it's worth a try

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to query on the selection right ?. If that was the case you can give a try like this

```
def selFunc(ctrlName):
    selectedValue = cmds.textScrollList(ctrlName, si=True, q=True)
    print selectedValue
cmds.window()
cmds.paneLayout()
cmds.textScrollList( "myControlObj", allowMultiSelection=True,sc="selFunc('myControlObj')",
            append=[ "red","greee","blue"],
            uniqueTag=["Albert Einstein","Rene Descartes"])
cmds.showWindow()
```

Comment: Na that's not what I want.  Using your code when I deselect something it prints none exactly like the code I wrote. I want to print what was deselected. So if I deselect red it will print red

Comment: I don't think so you can do that with native scrolllist. You probably need to consider using a pyqt widget.